# Isn´t it possible to create Azure DevOps project level group with Azure DevOps Python API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I´m trying to do some things with the Azure DevOps Python API (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api).
Been able to create projects, to enable and disable project modules and so on.

Now I got stuck with the creation of a projectlevel group.
What I found out is that in the identity client one can find "create_groups" endpoint. But it´s really not clear how to use it and also was not able to find anything helpful anywhere else.
I´m using v7_1 client in this case.

So with the normal rest API it´s absolutelly clear how to create a projectlevel group, but also thought there might be something in that Python API.

Thx a lot for your help!